# Добавление значения в выпадающее окно

Tags: php, html, sql

Как сделать так чтоб автоматически после создания записи в базе даниц, значение добавлялосьбы автоматически в

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="http://msg/users/test/test.php">1</option>
<option value="http://msg/users/test/test.php">2</option>
```

.................................

Comment: Вы меня простите, но у Вас очень плохо с формулированием сути вопроса.  Вы хотите - чтобы после добавления записи в БД у Вас эта запись появлялась в `selectbox`? Если так - то сделайте получение записей из БД и выводите их  в нужном месте.

Comment: Это я понял, но как это реализовать или посмотреть примеры не знаю. Может кто подскажет?

Comment: Вы находитесь там где нужно. Тут `тонны` примеров получения данных из СУБД и все сопутствующего. Ищущий да обрящет :)